# The nature of $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x,y) = y$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I understand that the question is perhaps not very specific, but what can one say about the nature of:
$$f(x,y)$$

If:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x,y) = y$$

Is this a known function, or is it used in any areas?

Edit:

Hypothesis

If I understand correctly, according to your hypothesis, any function $ f(x,y) $ with the property:

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x,y)=y$$

Can be constructed by taking any function $\phi(x,y)$ with finite limit:

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\phi(x,y)=c(y)$$

Associating it with same y and setting:

$$f(x,y):=\phi(x,y) - c(y) + y$$

Proof

Let:
$$f(x,y)=x\sin({y \over x}) $$

And let:
$$ \phi(x,y) = e^{1 \over |1+x|}y $$

Then, by definition:
$$ e^{1 \over |1+x|}y = x\sin({y \over x}) + \lim_{x\to\infty}{\big[e^{1 \over |1+x|}y\big]} + y $$

Let $y=1$. Since $\phi(x,y)$ is continuous near $\infty$, it is a valid operation to take the ln of both sides of the equation:

$$ \ln{\big[e^{1 \over |1+x|}\big]} = \ln{\big[x\sin\big({1 \over x}\big)\big]} + ln{\big[\lim_{x\to\infty}{e^{1 \over |1+x|}}\big]} + \ln{[1]} $$

Now, since:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{e^{1 \over |1+x|}=1}$$
It follows that:

$$ \ln{\big[e^{1 \over |1+x|}\big]} = \ln{\big[x\sin\big({1 \over x}\big)\big]} + 1 $$

Finally, let $x=1$. Hence:

$$ \ln{e^{1 \over 2}} = \ln[\sin(1)] + 1 $$
$$ 0.5 \approx -0.1726 + 1 $$
$$ 0.5 \approx 0.8274 $$

Conclusion

The assertion $f(x,y):=\phi(x,y) - c(y) + y$ is only true when $\phi(x,y) = f(x,y)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Maybe first you can think about the nature of $f$ if $f(a,y)=y$.

Answer (score 2):

This does not describe a function but an infinity of functions with a special (but not very interesting) property.

To build one, you can take any function that has a finite limit,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\phi(x)=c,$$ associate it to some $y$, and set

$$f(x,y):=\phi(x)-c+y.$$

Repeat for as many $y$'s and $\phi$'s as you want.

Example:

$$f(x,y):=\begin{cases}\text{odd}(\lfloor y^2\rfloor)\to\sqrt{x^2+2xy}-x,\\y<0\land\text{even}(\lfloor y^2\rfloor)\to\dfrac{\sin x}x+y.\end{cases}$$

Comment: +1, I like the generality of your answer. It seems however that this formulation does not describe all such functions. Take for example $f(x,y)=e^{\frac{1}{1+|x|}}y$. Do you believe, it could be possible to describe the set all functions with this property?

Comment: @Surb: yes, because I hid the fact that $\phi$ is implicitly a function of $y$ (because you have different $\phi$'s for different $y$'s). Hence you can take $\phi(x)=\exp(1/(1+|x|)y$, leading to $f(x,y):=\exp(1/(1+|x|)y-y+y$. (Please forgive me this notational neglience.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust much appreciated.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I see... so if I understand correctly, the general formulation is $f(x,y)=\phi(x,y)-c(y)+y$ with $\lim_{x\to \infty}\phi(x,y)=c(y)$ for all $y$.

Comment: @Surb: that's it. I could equally have said $\phi(x,y)\to0$ and $f(x,y)=\phi(x,y)+y$.